# In graphql / lighthouse I got "input." in sql-statement. How to fix it?

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Using input in  laravel 9 / lighthouse 6 app:

```
input VoteCategoryInput {
    name: String! @rules(apply: ["string", "min:2", "max:255", "unique:vote_categories"]),
    active: Boolean!,
    in_subscriptions: Boolean!,
    meta_description: String,
    meta_keywords: [String],
}


extend type Mutation {
   createVoteCategory(
       input: VoteCategoryInput! @spread
   ): VoteCategory! @create
```

and running mutation :

```
  mutation {
    createVoteCategory (
      input: {
        name: "Vote Category name"
        active: true
        in_subscriptions: true
        meta_keywords: ["meta_keywords 1", "meta_keywords 2"]
      }
    ) {
        id
        name
        slug
        in_subscriptions
        meta_description
        meta_keywords
        created_at
    }
  }
```

I got error :

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'input.name' in 'where clause'
 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `vote_categories` where `input`.`name` = Vote Category name)",
```

Which syntax have I to use to exclude “input.” in sql-statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lighthouse docs describe a caveat with the `unique` rule here: https://lighthouse-php.com/master/security/validation.html#validating-input-objects

Using the [`unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique)
validation rule can be a bit tricky.

If the argument is nested within an input object, the argument path will not
match the column name, so you have to specify the column name explicitly.

```
input CreateUserInput {
  email: String @rules(apply: ["unique:users,email_address"])
}
```